# base href url breaks <a href> anchor for fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla, fancybox

I've wrote some program that opens upon a link click.

```
<a class="myclass" href="#openfancybox">Open Fancybox</a>
```

It uses a fancybox, jQuery and everything works perfect.
Once I implemented it into the project, it doesn't work. The problem is this code in the project:

```
<base href="http://somesite.com/" />
```

It goes to the base url instead of opening a fancybox.

I've tried to fix it using jQuery or javascript solutions but I had no luck.

P.S. I don't want to remove `base` from the source code as it could break something else in the project (I have a task to implement my fancybox only).

P.P.S. Also I would definitely prefer a pure javascript solution as far as I use jQuery for my fancybox, but conflicts with other frameworks are expected. The project is for Joomla.

Comment: And tell us what is 'it' as you state that 'it' does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no conflict if you use a `base` tag and fancybox or whatsoever as you can see in **[this DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxANDbaseTag_26feb13.html)** ... and there is no need of additional javascript/jQuery to hack or fix the (non-existing) issue as previously suggested.

However, I presume that you clearly understand that the `base` tag will affect ALL your **relative paths** including your anchor `<a>` tags as well as your `<link>`, `<script>` and/or your `<img />` tags. In other words, any tag that uses the `href` and/or `src` attributes.

Having said that, consider this scenario :

Suppose that you have a page `test.html` which is located in a subdirectory called `sandobox`. The full path of such page would be `http://somesite.com/sandbox/test.html`, correct?

Now suppose that you are loading fancybox from within `test.html` using relative paths like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
```

... that is the equivalent of using the following absolute paths :

`http://somesite.com/sandbox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css` and `http://somesite.com/sandbox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js` respectively.

Now, if you decide to add a `base` tag like this :

```
<base href="http://somesite.com/" />
```

... all your relative paths, inlcuding your calls to fancybox files will be converted to :

`http://somesite.com/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css` and `http://somesite.com/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js`.

Since the fancybox file are actually located under the `sandbox` subdirectory, your document won't be able to load them (because the `base` tag) so your fancybox implementation will fail.

To solve the conflict, you could either do :

- Use absolute paths in your `<link>` and `<script>` tags or
- Relocate your files in relation to the `base` path.

Check this good question/answer about the `base` tag [Is it recommended to use the <base> html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1889076/1055987)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still happens upon this. There actually is a conflict to using base href with fancybox.

There is a check in Fancybox that looks at the `href` of the element clicked on and checks for the `#` symbol and if it finds that it sets the type as inline.

https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/blob/master/source/jquery.fancybox.js#L303

This works fine without using `<base href>`, but if you use that then the `href` attribute will return the full url with the hash, so the check that looks for `href.charAt(0) === '#'` will fail, because the first chat is no longer `#`, but probably an h.

Maybe instead of checking `charAt(0) === '#'` it should just look for a `#` and do a split instead.

Comment: Interesting, will check it